# Windows keystores and certificates

Tags: windows, certificate, java

I've recently inherited a project with minimal documentation that performs digital signatures of documents and I've received a change request that has left me a little baffled.

The application is Java based, and makes use of Java Keystores (JKS) and uses the private key of the alias specified as a command line operation to digitally sign an input document. This all appears fairly straightforward to me, however the change request has left me confused.

The client has requested the ability to use "Windows" keystores (more specifically, the Windows-MY keystore which relates to personal certificates as far as I can tell). Now, my initial assumption is that what the client is requesting is simply not possible as this key store will only ever contain certificates, which can not be used for signing documents in any capacity. Am I incorrect, or will the Windows-MY keystore only ever contain a public certificate? I don't believe a private key would ever be embedded within one of these certificates.

Unfortunately there are a some communication difficulties so I'd like to make sure my reasoning is correct before proceeding any further.

Here's some more evidence to support my case (communication from the client):

Creating Windows Key Store (Exporting from Java  Keystore ) steps are here -

1. generate RSA key

   ```
    keytool -genkey -alias mykey -keyalg RSA -keystore my.jks -keysize 2048
   ```
2. Export Certificate from the above keystore:

   ```
    keytool -export -alias mykey -file mykey.crt -keystore my.jks

    Enter keystore password:  temp123

    Certificate stored in file <mykey.crt>
   ```
3. Install the above certificate in windows keystore.

a.      Double click on “mykey.crt” and click on Install certificate

b.      Select “Place all certificates in the following store” radio button and click “Browse” button to Added it in windows Certificate store.
c.      Check this certificate in WindowsMy store.

Unless I'm wrong, keytool will only ever generate a certificate type rather than an actual public/private key pair?

Any assistance or even affirmation would be greatly appreciated, apologies for the lack of clarity in the question but unfortunately this is all I have to work with at the moment.
Java or Windows specific answers would be helpful but even just confirmation of the basic principles would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows cert stores will definitely allow you to store private keys. That's actually one of the more preferred options for storing keys in Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you want to take a look at Oracle's documentation [[1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html)] on the `SunMSCAPI` provider, that can be used to access certificates and keys stored in the `Windows-MY` (Personal) and `Windows-ROOT` (Trusted Root Certification Authorities) stores.

There is a little code snippet as well, which seems to match your needs quite reasonably:

```
   KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    // Note: When a security manager is installed, 
    // the following call requires SecurityPermission 
    // "authProvider.SunMSCAPI".
    ks.load(null, null); 

    byte[] data = ...
    String alias = "myRSA";

    PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, null);
    Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);

    Provider p = ks.getProvider();
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", p);
    sig.initSign(privKey);
    sig.update(data);
    byte[] signature = sig.sign();
    System.out.println("\tGenerated signature...");
    sig.initVerify(cert);
    sig.update(data);
    if (sig.verify(signature)) {
       System.out.println("\tSignature verified!");
    }
```

Summarizing: The Windows-My store holds certificates as well as private keys, both can be read from Java using the `SunMSCAPI` provider and can be used to sign digital documents.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to read personal keys, not from Java Keystore, but those I import to explorers, both from Windows and GNU/Linux and Mac OS? As I can tell, `SunMSCAPI` only exists in Windows.

Comment: @FaithReaper are you the OP? Question is specific to Windows: "Windows keystores and certificates" and is 4 years old. If you need to do this cross-platform you'll need to write your own wrapper for this that encapsulates the platform specific logic...

Comment: I know this is an old post, but using 'Windows-ROOT' to add the certificate creates a pop-up asking if i am sure i want to add this. At this point it becomes a manual process. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @nahzor I noticed this myself some time ago. There is no workaround that I'm aware of using plain Java. I went to the dark side and wrote some tiny Powershell scripts for this job. Using [jPowerShell](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell) these can easily be integrated into a Java project. However this of course requires Powershell to be installed...

Answer (score 0):

If simply wanting to use a keytool created (java) keystore's certificate w/ its private key so that you can import it into a windows, then would you just export it to PKCS12 format (PFX).  (i.e.; when exporting, use paramter  -storetype=pkcs12)